# Invoke parent method IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

In other browsers i can invoke parent method from `__proto__` property. But it not work in IE8. Is there a way to invoke parent method in IE8?

Code example:

```
function Foo() {
    this.init = function (msg) {
        alert("super method invoked");
    };

    this.toString = function () {
        return "Foo";
    }
}

FooExtended.prototype = new Foo();

function FooExtended() {
    this.init = function (msg) {
        if (this.__proto__ == undefined) {
            alert("super invoke not supported")
        } else {
            this.__proto__.init(msg);
        }
    };

    this.toString = function () {
        return "FooExtended";
    }
}

var foo = new FooExtended();
foo.init();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
  this.__proto__.init(msg)
```

try

```
  Foo.prototype.init.apply(this, msg);
```

Comment: This gives message in console `Foo.prototype.init` null or not Object

Comment: @Mrusful, ok, move the definition of Foo.prototype.init outside the constructor, i.e. declare it as a var and assign its value as the function. Also, instead of apply, use call.

Comment: Do you know what the difference between `Foo.prototype.init(this)` and `FooExtended.prototype.init(this)`? Where `this` is context of `FooExtended`. If look on example above.